# Autocomplete section in Selenium

Tags: selenium

I have the list which has multiple links under each section. Each section has different links. I need to click a particular link under each section. I have written the below code but when it executes, I'm not able to click the second section of autocomplete field after clicking the first section autocomplete field.
Here is my code. By using for-each am not able to select the second autocomplete field.

```
public class Autocomplete {
    
public static WebDriver driver;

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    
    ChromeOptions option = new ChromeOptions();
    
    option.addArguments("--disable-notifications");
    
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",".//src//browser//chromedriver.exe");

    driver = new ChromeDriver(option);
    
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    
    System.out.println("Browser Launch chrome");
    
    driver.get("https://www.redbus.in/");
    
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"src\"]")).sendKeys("ta");
    
    AutocompleteRedbus.RebBus(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"src\"]"), "Tambaram, Chennai");
    
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"dest\"]")).sendKeys("pon");
    
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    
    AutocompleteRedbus.RebBus(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"dest\"]"), "Ponamaravathi");  
}

}
```

Above mentioned AutocompleteRedbus calling method code here:

```
public class AutocompleteRedbus extends Autocomplete{


public static void RebBus(By xpath , String text) throws InterruptedException {
                   
    List<WebElement> listOfLinks = driver.findElements(By.xpath("xpath"));
    listOfLinks.forEach(link -> {
        if (link.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("text")) {
            link.click();
            }
        });
    }
  }
```

Comment: _Autocomplete_ for which field? Which _option(suggestion)_ do you want to select?

Answer (score 0):

When you are trying to select the value from the autocompleter, the xpath you are using is incorrect. Please change the xpath with the one i am providing and it would work fine.

```
AutocompleteRedbus.RebBus(By.xpath("//li[contains(@select-id,'results')]"), "Tambaram, Chennai");
```

And same for the destination method, like:

```
AutocompleteRedbus.RebBus(By.xpath("//li[contains(@select-id,'results')]"), "Ponamaravathi");
```

Comment: The place of results, What I have to paste if it will be the text of selected option?

Comment: see my line of code I had made some changes.                        AutocompleteRedbus.RebBusruncode(By.xpath("//li[contains(@results[0], 'results')]"), "Tambaram, Chennai");

Comment: The method that you have written in your question is correct you just need to pass the correct xpath into it, which you can do by using the code of line i have used in the answer. Please try that and let me know if it works.

Comment: It's not working..  but I just need to know that you have given xpath. In "@select-id" part ill paste the respective select id of that element and "results" part what I have to paste?.  please give one example for what I have to change in xpath of  "results" part.

Comment: Ok, so if you want to click the first element from the autocompleter, you can use `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"src\"]")).sendKeys("ta");`(which you are already using) and then use `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[contains(@select-id,'results')][1]")).click();` and it would click the first element from the dropdown. Let me know if this works for you